# write python object __str__ to file

Tags: python, file-io

```
class C:
    pass

file = open("newfile.txt", "w")

for j in range(10):
    c = C()
    print c
    file.write(c)

file.close()
```

Is there anything wrong in this code?
I am new to python and want to write the content that's outputted by `'print c'` to file ?

Comment: I suggest that you read: [InputOutput](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Was  there  a problem when you ran it?

Comment: In Python 2, you can use `print >>file, c` to send the output of a [`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) to the file. In Python 3 the [`print()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print) uses a keyword argument to do this, i.e. `print(c, file=file)`. A `file`'s `write()` method does not automatically call an object's `__str__()` method like `print` does, so you'd need do it explicitly via `file.write(str(c)+'\n')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `str()` function to convert an object to a string the same way `print` does:

```
for j in range(10):
    c = C()
    print c
    file.write(str(c))
```

This will not include a newline, however. If you need a newline as well, you can manually add one:

```
file.write(str(c) + '\n')
```

or use string formatting:

```
file.write('{}\n'.format(c))
```

or use the `print` statement with redirection (`>> fileobject`):

```
print >> file, c
```

Comment: I'd add a mention to the `print_function`.